# Background for Hamburger Menu Items in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that is styled correctly with a semi-transparent background on non-xs screens, but when it switches to the hamburger menu the subsequent menu items have no background whatesoever, which makes them hard to read. (In the image the reason "Man Rules" has a transparent background is that it is being hovered over.)

[image]

I would love to find a way to give these all the same `$transparent-black` background I have for the main navbar (I'm using SASS).

Here's my html/erb for the navbar:

```
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><%= image_tag 'LogoTextWhite.png', style: "height: 50px; margin-top: -15px" %></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to 'Man Rules', rules_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'BBQ', home_bbq_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Jokes', home_jokes_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Lifehacks', home_lifehacks_path %></li>
        <% if current_user %>
          <li><%= link_to user_path(current_user) do %>
            My Mancard <span style="background-color: red; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-radius: 7px"><%= current_user.manpoints %></span>
          <% end %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Log In', new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- custom-bootstrap-menu -->
```

And here's my SCSS:

```
/* NAVIGATION */
#custom-bootstrap-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
   z-index: 10 !important;
 }

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: $font-sans;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: $transparent-black !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: $transparent-black !important;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: white;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: white !important; /* Change border color around this buttons */
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: white !important; /* Change color for horizontal lines */
}
```

Can anyone help me figure this one out?  I've looked at SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794166/bootstrap-navbar-background-colour-of-dropdown-menu-item) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998677/bootstrap-3-navbar-and-collapse-menu-different-background-colors), but I still can't get it to work.  Bonus points if you can help me get rid of that awkward white line on the xs menu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I used on a recent project.

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    background: RGBA(0,0,0,0.85);
}
```

The key here is `.in` which is applied via the Bootstrap JS when the navigation is displayed (and of course, collapsed).

Comment: Thank you!  That was driving me crazy.  Good to know about `.in` as well.